# IIS redirect with url exception for stripe

Tags: node.js, iis, url-rewriting, stripe-payments

I'm working on updating the stripe checkout from a website, I was doing it successfully on localhost but when I put it on live mode on a windows server it stopped working. The issue is that when I should be redirected to the checkout page from stripe, the url is altered and becomes something that doesn't make sense:

The correct url: [www.checkout.stripe.com/pay/cs_..](http://www.checkout.stripe.com/pay/cs_..).
The url that I get redirected to: [www.mysite.com/pay/cs_.](http://www.mysite.com/pay/cs_.).

I kept thinking what could be the causa of that and I think it's the URL rewrite rule that I have on the windows server. I would like to add an exception to the rule and allow the stripe checkout to initiate, but I have no idea how to do it.

Below is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>                 
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8008/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="HTTPS" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you could try condition like this " <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.checkout.stripe.com" negate="true" /> "

Comment: @JalpaPanchal thanks but to no avail. It didn't work

Comment: try to set up FREB at your side https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. This is my final web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" />
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8008/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="stripe redirect in checkout" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/pay/" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="checkout.stripe.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>
```

My issue was not really understanding the meaning of the options in the URL Rewrite. I checked the course [URL Rewrite for Developers](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/url-rewrite-for-developers/table-of-contents) and it was really helpful. I was able to solve the issue quickly.

Comment: If this solution worked for you, then you've created a looped request to your server, which you should resolve with a special rewrite rule. When you create a `checkout session`, it contains the [correct URL](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url) that you should redirect to. I'm omitting the possibility that you're using your [custom domain](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-domains) for checkout, because you believe that the correct URL to the Checkout Session uses domain `checkout.stripe.com`.

Answer (score 1):

The file you have shown contains the **inbound** rewrite rules only. But you have an issue with response from your server. Thus, you should fix the **outbound** rewrite rule in the right config file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the reasoning, but I find it hard to know exactly how to setup the rule. Do you have any resources that might help and you could share? I found a few but I get a bit lost in the patterns and I'm not sure if the rules don't work because they don't or because I wrote them poorly. Thank you!

Comment: First of all, you should find the right config file. The file you posted here doesn't seem to be from the site you're having the problem on. It is likely that you can choose not to fix the outbound rewrite rules, but to remove them as unnecessary.